# Применение стилей ко всем дочерним элементам блока

Tags: css

Есть стиль, который берет все элементы на странице и закрашивает их в серый цвет и прочее.
Но я хочу, чтобы эти стили применялись только ко всем дочерним элементам блока **main_block** .
Не могу понять, как это сделать.

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  /* Эти стили должны примениться только к дочерним элементам  main_block */
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block ">

  <div class="text "> Текст</div>
  <div class="images ">Картинка</div>
  <div class="content ">Контент</div>

</div>
```

Как выбрать все дочерни элементы родительского блока?

Answer (score 3):

Вот так вот, `>` присваивает всем элементам которые находится в этом элементе

```css
.main_block > *,
.main_block > *:after,
.main_block > *:before{
    box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="main_block ">

  <div class="text "> Текст</div>
  <div class="images ">Картинка</div>
  <div class="content ">Контент</div>

</div>
```

Comment: Вы забыли про before и after, посмотрите внимательно на мой код

Comment: @Домик всё, изменил. Какой (-ая) ты капризный (-ая) ))

Comment: @Домик ну и как? помогло?

Comment: Нет =( Вы сколько лет изучаете CSS?

Comment: @Black_Viper наверное больше чем вы ^-^